# The format string for DateTime.ParseExact - what hour format works with "tt"?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython

I want to convert string 5/4/2017 2:15:50 PM to a datetime. I used

```
statustime="5/4/2017 2:15:50 PM"
statustimefrm=DateTime.Parse(statustime, Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

and it worked, but I would rather use ParseExact. I used

```
statustimefrm=DateTime.Parse(statustime,  "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

but it gave me a format error. Would anybody know the format to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
DateTime.ParseExact(timespan, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: changed it to DateTime.ParseExact(timespan, "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 5):

"HH" is not compatible with "tt" - you either have 24 hour time or 12 hours plus AM/PM designators. You need to use [`h` for time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier):

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("5/4/2017 2:15:50 PM",  "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",
       new CultureInfo("en-US"))
```